# User-defined and standard conversions

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Why doesn't the following code compile?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct CL1{};

struct CL2:CL1
{
    CL2(int){cout<<"int";}
};

void fnc(const CL1&)
{
}

int main()
{
    fnc(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Isn't two conversions working?

1. user-defined conversion `int` to `CL2`
2. standard conversion derived-to-base (`CL2` to `const CL1&`)

The standard (2003) says:

> A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard conversion sequence followed by a user-defined conversion (12.3) followed by a second standard conversion sequence.

Why does this not work?

Comment: I'm not used with the standard itself, but if this was working, the compiler would need to check for all valid (non-explicit) constructors of all subclasses of a class. This could create some interesting issues with code that "magically" compiles when you add a seemingly unrelated header (containing some subclass) or collisions of constructors of different classes

Comment: Hmmm...I don't know what the standard says on the matter, but being that you could have multiple roots from int to CL1 if this was allowed (say, if you have a CL3 that is identical to CL2), I'd guess that this would be complained about somewhere else in the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no standard conversions involving references, so that rule isn't relevant here. Instead, we need the rules for initialising references, given in C++11 8.5.3. These are quite complicated; the relevant one here is the final bullet of clause 5 (for the case where the initialiser isn't reference-compatible with the reference type):

> a temporary of type `cv1 T1` is created and initialized from the initializer expression
>   using the rules for a non-reference copy-initialization

Here, `cv1 T1` is `const CL1`. There is no way to create a temporary `T1` from `int`, and so the initialisation fails. The compiler isn't required to search all types derived from, or convertible to, the reference type; it only considers the reference type itself. You will have to specify that you want to create a `CL2`:

```
func(CL2(5));
```

which, being reference-compatible with `const CL1`, can be used to initialise the reference.

<sub>NOTE: I'm quoting C++11 since that's been the standard for some years. The rules and section numbers were essentially the same in C++03 (and indeed C++98).</sub>